# Intregation in complex analysis - homotopy

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $U := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \;\mbox{ s. t. } |z| > c \}$ with $c<1$ and suppose that $\lim_{z\to \infty} f(z) = 0$.
Is it true that \begin{equation*} w_k = \int_{S_1} \frac{f(z)}{z^k}\frac{\text{d} z}{z} \end{equation*} is $0$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? Or is it only true for a subset (e. g. the naturals) ?

If yes, can we prove it using homotopy of curves ?

Comment: What is $S_1$? What have you tried? What are your thoughts? From where is this problem?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).